# Changing text color of one form but not the other?

Tags: css, wordpress, wpbakery

I feel like I'm missing something here and this is becoming more complicated than it should be.
Basically, in the first section of my site I have a contact form to fill out that I need to have white text as the labels. I am trying to implement this code to show up for my top contact form, but keep the same black text on my bottom contact form

`form label { color: #ffffff; }`

I've tried working with the extra class names inside WPBakery which I've used many times before but obviously something is not working right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Obviously what you have will select all your labels in all your forms. Use classes, IDs, a combo, or any of the other special selectors to target your specific form. Without a [mcve] showing your HTML we cant offer much else in terms of advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Classes to define CSS properties seems like the best approach. It would be helpful to see what you have tried and what's not working in your code.

defining one class as .formSchema1 and another as .formSchema2 and setting the desired color respectively using { color: #ffffff; } and { color: #000000; }

Comment: I knew it was something extremely simple. I was using ID selectors. I literally just changed the '#' in my code to a '.' and it worked. Been a while since I've done this, obviously lol. Thanks so much!